# Symfony - Multiple hosts, dynamic default one

Tags: symfony

I have a website with multiple hosts: domain1 and domain2. 
But when I'm accessing to website with **domain2**, all my routes are like

> domain1.com/url.

but should be

> domain2.com/url

Is it possible somehow get current host and pass it to the `routes.yml`?

Here is my config:

```
shop:
    host:     "www.{domain}"
    resource: "@WebShopBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    schemes:  [https]
    defaults:
        domain: domain1.com
    requirements:
        domain: domain1.com|domain2.com
```

Thanks

Comment: to use the current host just remove the host option on line 2.

Comment: What about subdomain? something.{domain}? I can't remove host.